# No funciona el comando git push

Tags: git, github, git-push, push, pull

Tengo un problema con la función `push` para subir los cambios realizados.
Cuento con dos dispositivos el dispositivo al que llamaremos *"hogar"* que es desde donde se subió el proyecto puede usar push y pull normalmente y sin problemas.
ahora el segundo dispositivo denominado *"trabajo"* el cual uso en los ratos libres para avanzar en el proyecto no me deja usar la función push pero si la función pull
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar cambios en mi proyecto y usar el comando `git status` si me detecta los cambios, el `git commit` si funciona pero al momento de usar el `git push origin` se traba y no lo realiza.

esta captura es del segundo dispositivo "trabajo"

Comment: Probablemente por https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic

Comment: Nos dejaste en suspenso... con el resultado del push.